# How to bundle a graphql project that uses fileloaders? for example graphql-tools

Tags: javascript, graphql, path, esbuild, graphql-tools

I am trying to bundle my `graphql` server using `esbuild`.
The problem Im having is when everything is bundled together `graphql-tools` cant find `resolvers` and `typeDefs` due to the file running in a diffrent directory meaning a diffrent `__dirname`.

My `schema.js` file:

```
import { makeExecutableSchema } from '@graphql-tools/schema';
import { loadFilesSync } from '@graphql-tools/load-files';
import { mergeResolvers, mergeTypeDefs } from '@graphql-tools/merge';
import path from "path";

const typesArray = mergeTypeDefs(loadFilesSync(path.join(__dirname, '/types') , {extensions:['gql']}))
const resolversArray = mergeResolvers(loadFilesSync(path.join(__dirname, './resolvers') , { recursive: true }))
export const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  resolvers: resolversArray,
  typeDefs: typesArray
})
```

I tried copying the `resolvers` and `typedefs` to the `dist` folder prebuild but im looking for a better solution.
I also tried using absolute paths but that won't work if i create an image out of the `dist` folder since it wont recognize the folder `src` anymore.